# ASP MVC 4 - caching action filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, action-filter

I have a simple action filter attribute that checks if user is currently online:

```
public class CheckForOnlineAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         Membership.GetUser();
         base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
     }
}
```

Now, i would like to cache this action for 12 minutes, i tried putting a `[OutputCache(Duration=XXX)]` on it, but that does not work. How can i cache this action filter?

Comment: Define "cache" the filter. You want the filter to only be invoked every 12 minutes? How does it vary? I don't think you've thought this all the way through, since this result would be cached for everyone going through this.

Comment: I want it to execute every 12 minutes for every single user - user is logging in, action is being invoked, and after 12 minutes it is being executed once again.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Duration is in seconds, so not 12 but 1200 in your Duration (I see you've now changed that to XXX but I saw it as 12)

You would also want this action to include a parameter for user and vary by parameter for outputcache.

Comment: Yeah i changed that, i was hoping to avoid people telling me that this is in seconds, i had 12 seconds in my code and pasted it here without editing. :-) Anyway thanks for pointing a bug.